# Get ICollection out from IQueryable<ICollection> LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to write a query that grabs a list of countries out from my joined data.
`Places` is `List<Country>`.

```
        var zonedCountries = (from dz in db.DeliveryZones.Include(d => d.Places)
                              where model.DeliveryZones.Contains(dz.ID)
                              select dz.Places);
```

I would expect `zonedCountries` to be a List but instead it is a `IQueryable<ICollection<Country>>`.

How do I extract the list from this?

Comment: Are you looking for a `List<Country>` or a `List<List<Country>>` or an `IQueryable<List<Country>>` or..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get flattened list of countries:

```
var zonedCountries = (from dz in db.DeliveryZones.Include(d => d.Places)
                      where model.DeliveryZones.Contains(dz.ID)
                      from p in dz.Places
                      select p);
```

Or use `SelectMany`:

```
var zonedCountries = db.DeliveryZones.Include(d => d.Places)
                       .Where(dz => model.DeliveryZones.Contains(dz.ID))
                       .SelectMany(dz => dz.Places);
```

BTW I'm not sure if you need to include places manually in this case (thus you are selecting places instead of delivery zones). And you will probably want to select distinct countries only - `Distinct()` will help you here. Also if you want to store results in list, then simple `ToList()` call will do the job.

Comment: I've never seen the from - blah - from syntax before. Many thanks :)

Comment: SelectMany? something new every day... you sir deserves your +1